# How can I execute something between instantiation of the user control and OnInit call?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, page-lifecycle

What is the simplest solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Control adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx) are the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the closest you can get:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775(VS.71).aspx) `Init` is the very first event invoked on a control. In other words: there are no extension points between the constructor and the `OnInit()` method call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it's possible.

Here is the execution lifecycle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775(VS.71).aspx

Maybe if you share what you are trying to accomplish someone could offer an alternative approach.